# Available options for the ACTION_WEB_SEARCH RecognizerIntent

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am studying how the `android.speech` package works and I noticed that most of the extras used with the intent `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` are ignored by the speech recognizer.

- If I set a language using the `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE` extra, the specified language is ignored, but the default language of the device is always used.
- If I set a text using the `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT`, this text is not displayed.
- If I start the speech recognition activity using `startActivityForResult` method, then the speech recognizer calls `onActivityResult`, but the second argument (the `resultCode`) is always `RESULT_CANCELED` and the third argument (the data `Intent`) is always `null`. This behavior is probably due to the fact that the purpose of this type of intent is to perform a search on the web. For the same reason, if I set the maximum number of results using `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS`, the specified value is ignored.

I found this behavior, but the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH) says that these options can also be used for the `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` intent.

Why does the actual behavior of the voice recognition system differ from what is stated in official documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong action. Instead of `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`, use [`ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH).

If you do, `onActivityResult` will behave as you expect and your Activity will be in control of interpreting the recognition results.

By the way, when you set ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, you delegate handling of the results to Android. Based on what the user says, Android might start a web browser or it might start an email (if the user says "email"). Because of this it makes sense that your Activity does not receive any useful information, although I think it should still take into account RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE.

Comment: Well, I've used `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` and I verified that all the extras work. But I do not understand why some extras are not available for `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`: probably the reason for this behavior is that this type of intent does not return results to the calling activity.
I am surprised that the `EXTRA_LANGUAGE` extra does not work: if I set another language than the default, the "Speak now" dialog displays the specified language, but the spoken words are not recognized. Instead, the the `EXTRA_LANGUAGE` extra works using the `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` intent.

Comment: I agree the same language string should work for both intents